# Correlated asset paths to derive VaR

Tags: stochastic-processes, monte-carlo

So I wanted to generate a Monte Carlo simulation for two correlated assets to derive then the VaR as a quantile of the generated distributions. My code is the following, where the input parameters are correlation = 1, yearly volatility of both asset 30% and the starting prices are 100 for asset 1 and 80 for asset 2:

```
SDAsset1 = 0.3
SDAsset2 = 0.3

Corr = 1
Cov = SDAsset1*SDAsset2*Corr

cov_matrix <- matrix(c(SDAsset1^2, Cov, Cov,  SDAsset2^2), nrow = 2)
cov_matrix
mu = c(0,0)
x<- mvrnorm(100000, mu,cov_matrix)

return1 <- x[,1]
return2 <- x[,2]

asset1 <- exp(return1)*100
asset2 <- exp(return2)*80

quantile(asset1, 0.9)
quantile(asset2, 0.9)
```

My question is now how would I have to change the code and parameters such that I could get the distribution after 1/2 year. My approach would be to take the volatility and divide it by the square root of 2, but I'm not sure where I would have to change the time step.

Comment: The size of the time step is implied; you are taking just one step, which is prescribed to have this multivariate normal distribution. If the underlying model is supposed to be geometric Brownian motion, then yes, the volatility scales in the way that you've suggested.

Comment: @ChrisHaug so the only thing I would have to change is to adjust the volatility is that correct?

Comment: The mean has to scale as well, although here it is zero so doesn't matter.